# How much storage does a tent have in DayZ?

Tags: dayz-2012

How much storage does a tent have in DayZ?

What happens if I try to put things in when its full?

Comment: Do note: You can place items into backpacks into tents for added inventory space.

Comment: That is not recommended as those items can be wiped during a server reset.

Comment: That's only if a server admin chooses to reset the server correctly, which I've never seen. There are various ways to prevent the wipe, although some of them are tent save glitches.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find this information here - [How Tent Storage Works in DayZ - Scare Bears Clan](http://scarebearsclan.com/dayz/how-tent-storage-works-in-dayz/).

> This answer is current as of version 1.7.2.3
>
> **Ok so rule 1:** In a tent every item counts as 1 slot. That means your m4a1 is 1 slot, a tire is 1 slot, a jerrycan is 1 slot, anything
> and everything is 1 slot when inside a tent.
>
> Storage is broken down into 3 different categories, each one has it’s
> own amount of storage space.
>
> - Weapons & Tools(including NV goggles, binoculars, and side arms) – 10    Slots
> - Backpacks – 5 Slots
> - Items – 50 Slots
>
> So an example of a full tent would be:
>
> 5 AKM’s, 2 Binoculars, 2 M1911
> Pistols, 1 NV goggles. = 10 Slots
> 5 Alice Packs. = 5 Slots
> 10 tires, 5
> jerrycans, 20 bloodbags, 5 Stanag Ammo, 10 Raw Meat. = 50 Slots.
>
> So as you can see it doesn’t matter how many slots the item would take in
> your inventory, it only counts as 1 slot within the tent.
>
> If you attempt to place items into a full tent one of two things can
> happen. The item can drop on the floor near the tent or the item could
> disappear. So take care when placing items in the tent.
>
> My personal theory on items disappearing after placing in a full tent
> is — the items are placed under the tent or perhaps under the ground
> if your tent is on a hill.